# Having trouble with C++ variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, parameters, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, variadic

I'm trying to write a generic function for logging some stuff for debugging, and I want to call it for example like so:

```cpp
Log("auo", 34); //writes: auo34

Point point;
point.X = 10;
point.Y = 15;
Log(35, point, 10); //writes: 35{10, 15}10
```

However, I'm having all kinds of problems with parameter packing and unpacking, I can't seem to get the hang of it. Below is the full code:

```
struct Point {
     long X, Y;
}

std::ofstream debugStream;

template<typename ...Rest>
void Log(Point first, Rest... params) {  //specialised for Point
    if (!debugStream.is_open())
        debugStream.open("bla.log", ios::out | ios::app);
    debugStream << "{" << first.X << ", " << first.Y << "}";
    Log(params...);
}

template<typename First, typename ...Rest>
void Log(First first, Rest... params) {  //generic
    if (!debugStream.is_open())
        debugStream.open("bla.log", ios::out | ios::app);
    debugStream << first;
    Log(params...);
}
```

How do I fix the functions please?

Comment: You need to provide a base case for the last recursive call when the parameter pack will be empty and a call to `Log()` will be evaluated. Adding a `void Log() {}` overload should be enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the following simplified version:

```
void print() {}

template<typename First, typename... Rest>
void print(const First& first, const Rest&... rest)
{
    std::cout << first;
    print(rest...);
}
```

When `sizeof...(Rest) == 0` a call to `print()` with no parameters will be issued which requires the base case overload above.